# Why is this circuit not powering my LED?

Tags: mosfet, led

Circuit uses an IRFZ44N MOSFET. [image: picture of circuit]

I am trying to learn to power an LED with a MOSFET to eventually be able to reverse the polarity of a motor with 4 MOSFETs and a microcontroller.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have the MOSFET connections mixed up. According to https://components101.com/mosfets/irfz44n-datasheet-pinout-features left is gate, middle is drain, right is source. You have the LED connected to the gate.

Comment: And in case you're worried, the MOSFET will be just fine after connecting it this way unless your voltage source is ridiculously high for some reason (like 30V).

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea on how I could reverse the polarity of a circuit using MOSFETs?

Comment: @wandyrge the circuit you're going to make is called an *H-bridge* - look that up

Answer (score 1):

User user253751 is right, you have connected the MOSFET incorrectly. There's another possible concern though: often the four long power buses are split into two halves, the splits shown in green here:

[image]

The top leg of your LED may not be connected to anything, and you'll have to bridge that split with a wire link.

Comment: Just a note: While this is generally correct, and always something to look at, there is an indication: The red and blue lines are commonly separated at the location of the split. The OP's board has lines passing all over the length. A simple continuity check will reveal a possible split.